# How can I make two objects to spin slowly to full speed then back to minimum speed smooth?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spin : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] droidJets;

    public float rotationSpeedMin = 0;
    public float rotationSpeedMax = 180;
    public float currentSpeed = 0;
    public float acceleration = 1;

    private void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

I want to make the jets to spin on the x only and nonstop to accelerate up to max speed then back to min speed and slowly smooth like giving the spin a power to speed up and speed down using the acceleration.

I tried this :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spin : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] droidJets;

    public float rotationSpeedMin = 0;
    public float rotationSpeedMax = 180;
    public float currentSpeed = 0;
    public float acceleration = 100f;

    void Update()
    {
        acceleration = currentSpeed += Time.deltaTime;

        for (int i = 0; i < droidJets.Length; i++)
        {
            droidJets[i].transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * acceleration * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

but the acceleration is very slow it's taking a lot of time the objects to speed up. and how can I make that if they get to the max speed they will start slowly smooth to speed down back to min ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is instead of the
acceleration=currentSpeed+=Time.deltaTime;

you could use the Mathf.Lerp function to go from your minimum speed to maximum speed.

```
if(acceleration < MaximumSpeed&&IncreaseAcceleration)
    acceleration=Mathf.Lerp(MinimumSpeed,MaxmimumSpeed,0.125f);

if(acceleration > MaximumSpeed) {
    IncreaseAcceleration = false;
    Acceleration = Mathf.Lerp(MaximumSpeed,MinimumSpeed,0.125f);
}
```